# How to register a VS Code task which invokes a function

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am developing a new extension which uses tasks. I need to create a task which will call a function, rather than starting a new process or shell.

I can create a new task which can execute a shell command.

```ts
let task = new vscode.Task(kind, taskName, taskSource, new vscode.ShellExecution(`echo Hello World`));
```

I would like to make a task which will call another method. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There happens to be a ["proposed API"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api) for this exact purpose:

- ["custom execution" section](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_33#_custom-task-execution) in the March 2019 release notes with a code example:

  ```ts
  let execution = new vscode.CustomExecution((terminalRenderer, cancellationToken, args): Thenable<number> => {
          return new Promise<number>(resolve => {
              // This is the custom task callback!
              resolve(0);
          });
      });
  const taskName = "First custom task";
  let task = new vscode.Task2(kind, vscode.TaskScope.Workspace, taskName, taskType, 
  execution);
  ```
- original issue: [Allow extension to provide callback functions as tasks (#66818)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66818)
- initial implementation [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/66819)
- relevant section in [`vscode.proposed.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/b7f20a8b514bf9804298cda05061277fb200664f/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts#L1324-L1364)